# Re-sizing screen not the expected size

Tags: window, processing

```
int displayX, displayY;
final int screenX=200, screenY=200; // display size

void setup() {
  background(255);
  displayX=displayWidth;
  displayY=displayHeight;
  size(screenX, screenY);
}

void mouseClicked() {
  if (width==screenX) {
    frame.setSize(displayX, displayY);
    setSize(displayX, displayY);
    println(width +" "+height);
  } else {
    frame.setSize(screenX, screenY);
    setSize(screenX, screenY);
    println(width +" "+height);
  }
}

void draw() {
  fill(33, 33, 33);
  rect(0, 0, screenX, screenY);
  fill(77, 77, 77);
  rect(0, 0, screenX-20, screenY-20);
}
```

[full code](http://report.rala.io/code/processing/star_150611.txt)
*press b to start beta - left mouse click change the size*

I want a small size on startup (screenX).
After a click it grows to the display size.
After another click it gets the small size again.

But after changing the size the sizes aren't correct.
I see that on the border. I've everywhere a border around my "star". But this is only on top and left correct.

I also tested it with a lineal.

*Processing 2.2.1

Windows 7*

Comment: You should post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)- not your full code, but enough that we can copy and paste it to actually run it.

Answer (score 0):

Step one is to check out the [Processing reference](https://www.processing.org/reference/).

From the [size()](https://www.processing.org/reference/size_.html) documentation:

> The size() function can only be used once inside a sketch, and it cannot be used for resizing.

So, you can't use the `size()` function the way you're trying to use it. Instead, you can access the `frame` variable directly:

```
frame.setSize(200, 200);
```

You might toggle the frame's size like this:

```
boolean big = false;

void setup(){
  size(200, 200);
}

void mouseClicked(){
  if(big){
    frame.setSize(200, 200); //set the window size
    big = false;
  }
  else{
    frame.setSize(400, 400); //set the window size
    big = true;
  }
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
}
```

However, if you run that program, you might notice something like this:

[image: sketch screenshot]

The window has increased size, but the actual canvas where things get drawn hasn't. So you get a gray area, and mouse events aren't detected correctly. To fix that problem, you have to set the size of the canvas as well, by calling the `setSize()` function:

```
boolean big = false;

void setup(){
  size(200, 200);
}

void mouseClicked(){
  if(big){
    frame.setSize(200, 200); //set the window size
    setSize(200, 200); //set the canvas size
    big = false;
  }
  else{
    frame.setSize(400, 400); //set the window size
    setSize(400, 400); //set the canvas size
    big = true;
  }
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
}
```

Comment: fine, but I have the problem, that it is not exactly that size. It is a bit smaller. In my app (see the complete code link) I have a border. And that is a bit smaller after re-sizing.

Comment: @rala If you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'll be happy to help.